# Send Email To Users Depending On An Email Address In A Column Of Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a brilliant script that was given to me by @cooper that updates a sent column and sends an email everytime a new row is added to a google sheet using google apps script.

What I now want to do is instead of the email going to me (test@gmail.com) I want it to be send to an email address contained in column E.

Structure of google sheets can be seen below:

[image]

Can someone help?

```
function sendemail() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const sr = 2;
  const rg = sh.getRange(sr, 1, sh.getLastRow() - sr + 1, 6);
  const vs = rg.getValues();
  vs.forEach((r, i) => {
    let Subject = "New Content on IG.com";
    let message =
      "<p><b>Title: </b>" + r[0] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Article: </b>" + r[1] + "</p>";
    let EmailSent = r[5];
    let SendTo = "me@gmail.com";
    if (EmailSent != "Yes") {
      sh.getRange(i + sr, 6).setValue("Yes");
      MailApp.sendEmail({to: SendTo,cc: "",subject: Subject,htmlBody: message});
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would just be a matter of replacing the SendTo hardcoded value with that row column value.

```
let SendTo = r[4];
```

Comment: so sorry i meant column e and updated my pic - thank you